# How to minimize all code in notepad ++ using hotkey

Tags: notepad++

Hi all I once do it but now I don't remember. I need minimize all code using one hotkey combination 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Shortcut Mapper from **Settings -> Shortcut Mapper** I think you want *Fold All* which seems to be mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> by default,.

Interestingly, it only seems to work with the <kbd>0</kbd> in the row above the letters on the keyboard; using the number pad does not seem to work even with Num lock turned off.